# MS Teams - composeExtension set width for sign in action

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am not sure how to set the width of a messaging extension response when using `composeExtension` property. For a `task` I understand I can use a width/height property, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I've been looking at `MessagingExtensionActionResponse` but the `MessagingExtensionResult` type doesn't seem to have a place to set the width/height.

I am using the following (taken straight from [MS samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/a13f204ef5e00f60c3671d2a0d75d78c1f6388ea/samples/javascript_nodejs/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config/bots/teamsMessagingExtensionsSearchAuthConfigBot.js#L61))

```js
return {
    composeExtension: {
        type: 'auth',
        suggestedActions: {
            actions: [
                {
                    type: 'openUrl',
                    value: signInLink,
                    title: 'Bot Service OAuth'
                },
            ],
        },
    },
};
```

This is what it outputs (I am looking to reduce the width)

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ghojzilla, we are checking with our internal team, will update you soon.

Comment: Hi @Ghojzilla, could you please add width property for the above code and let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: Hi @Jagadeesh-MSFT, I mentioned in my question there didn't seem to be anywhere to put the width property after checking the MessagingExtensionActionResponse, so I was not sure where to add this property, so I added it to them all! Sadly, still no luck, the width remains the same.

Comment: {width: "500",composeExtension: { type: 'auth', width: "500", suggestedActions: { width: "500", actions: [{ type: 'openUrl', value: signInLink, title: 'Bot Service OAuth', width: "500", }, ], }, }, }

Comment: Hi @Ghojzilla, I have tried it from my end , currently it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks @Jagadeesh-MSFT, is there any plans to add this in? I can raise this on the git hub repo

Comment: As this feature is not available at present, could you please raise an [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available at present.